# How to know if you're in a typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'm using the `script` command to save all the output from the terminal to a file called `typescript`. Or `script foo` to save to the file `foo`.

Now, let's say I'm going along typing command after command and I forget whether or not I'm in a typescript or not.

How can I find out if I'm within a typescript or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe with:

```
if lsof -tac script "$(tty)" > /dev/null; then
  echo "I'm running under script"
else
  echo "I'm not"
fi
```

You could add something like:

```
lsof -tac script "$(tty)" > /dev/null && PS1="[script] $PS1"
```

To your `~/.zshrc` or `~/.bashrc`, so the information on whether you're in `script` or not would be visible on your shell prompt.

Alternatively, if you can't guarantee that `lsof` be installed you could do (assuming an unmodified IFS):

```
terminal=$(ps -o comm= -p $(ps -o ppid= -p $(ps -o sid= -p "$$")))
[ "$terminal" = script ] && PS1="[script] $PS1"
```

The heuristic is to get the command name of the parent of the session leader which generally would be the terminal emulator (`xterm`, `script`, `screen`...).

Comment: @teikakazura, the _heuristic_ part was because you're not guaranteed that it will be the parent process of the session leader. Nothing to do with pid reuse here as your session leader and its parent will typically still be around when you run that command. You could say that the first one is _heuristic_ as well as we're just checking the process name. Any command whose name is also `script` and has the tty open would also cause a false positive.

Comment: @teikakazura  About (2), that would check the ppid of the current shell. Here, you want to check the ppid of the session leader (typically, that would be the shell that `script` started).

Comment: I can't understand @StephaneChazelas comment here (what is "(2)", probably a deleted comment), but the second part of answer is very interesting as it can detect not only `script` but also other situations, like `su -l`, `ssh`, Linux console and perhaps others, and provide (through other arguments of `ps`) much more information.

Answer (score 5):

Interesting problem.  I found a small bash script could do the job pretty reliably:

```
#!/bin/bash

PP=$(ps -o ppid= $$)

while [[ $PP != 1 ]]
do
    LINE=$(ps -o ppid= -o comm= $PP | sed 's/^  *//')
    COMM=${LINE#* }
    PP=${LINE%% *}
    if [[ $COMM == script ]]  # Might need a different comparison
    then
        echo "In script"
        exit 0
    fi
done
echo "Not in script"
```

I think this is slightly different than proposed by Stephane Chazelas, in that my script works its way up the parent:child relationship that Linux/Unix processes have until it finds PID 1, or it finds "script" as the process.

Comment: Interesting approach. However, note that if for instance, you start an `xterm` from your script session, that script will thing the shell in that xterm is running under script. Well it is in a way, but the output is not going to the typescript. My approach checks the terminal associated with the current session so would not have that issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a personal bin/ directory in your path (e.g. /home/user/bin,
place a shell script there with the name 'script' (same name as the binary), with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/bash
export SCRIPT_RUNNING=1
exec /usr/bin/script # full path to your script(1) binary
```

Now, within script running, you can test for the environment variable SCRIPT_RUNNING, and do whatever you want based on it.

EDIT:

Actually, there's a far easier way. The following says it all, create three files, ~/bin/script, ~/bin/script-shell and ~/.scriptrc:

```
~ > ls ~/bin/script ~/bin/script-shell ~/.scriptrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 roadowl users 23 Oct 18 16:52 /home/roadowl/.scriptrc
-rwx------ 1 roadowl users 49 Oct 18 16:53 /home/roadowl/bin/script
-rwx------ 1 roadowl users 56 Oct 18 16:55 /home/roadowl/bin/script-shell

~/bin > cat script
#!/bin/bash
exec /usr/bin/script -c script-shell

~/bin > cat script-shell
#!/bin/bash
exec /bin/bash --rcfile /home/bjd/.scriptrc

~/bin > cat ~/.scriptrc
export PS1="[script] "
```

If your current shell is bash, don't forget to run `hash -r` after creating these files, to ensure ~/bin/script is run when 'script' is entered as a command (check with `which script`).

As before, note that you must have ~/bin in your PATH, preceding the standard path for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

For most use cases on localhost, checking the *SCRIPT* environment variable or for the existence of your expected output file is usually your best bet. However, there are a number of use cases where you're going to have to either explicitly set a variable or semaphore (either locally or on the remote), label your window (e.g. in GNU screen or tmux) or your terminal tab, or come up with some other solution that doesn't rely on implicit or default behaviors that may not apply in your particular situation.

I provide some examples below of how to check for the *SCRIPT* variable on BSD and Linux. I also offer some caveats, including the limitations of this approach when connecting to a remote host via SSH.

### BSD: Check *SCRIPT* Environment Variable

On systems that use BSD versions of `script`, you can check for the presence of the *SCRIPT* environment variable. BSD's script(1) says:

> The SCRIPT environment variable is added to the sub-shell. If SCRIPT already existed in the users environment, its value

For example, given:

```bsh
SHELL=/bin/sh script logfile.log
```

```bsh
# script exports SCRIPT to sub-shells, so you can test if
# it's non-empty
[ -n "$SCRIPT" ] && echo "in typescript"

# SCRIPT holds the name of the typescript file you specified,
# or "typescript" by default; his enables you to check if
# you're in a *specific* typescript
[ "$SCRIPT" = "logfile.log" ] || [ "$SCRIPT" = "typescript" ]

# returns name of typescript file or an error message
echo "${SCRIPT?not in typescript}"

# exit status 0 in typescript; show error message and return
# exit status 1 outside the typescript
: "${SCRIPT?not in typescript}"

# this is less reliable, but can be useful in some cases;
# true if in a sub-shell, although there are no guarantees
# the sub-shell was spawned by script
[ "$SHLVL" -gt "1" ]
```

### Linux: Export Your Own SCRIPT Variable

The version that comes with util-linux 2.23.2 (which is the version I have handy) doesn't export the SCRIPT variable by default. You can simply export your own, in whatever way you do that with your shell. In shells like Bash:

```bsh
SCRIPT='typescript' script
```

You can then do the same tests as above.

### Caveats

The `script` command allows you to specify a command to run rather than just starting a shell. So, if your command cleans the environment (e.g. `env -i printenv`), unsets your SCRIPT variable, or is on a remote system (e.g. logging in via SSH) then *SCRIPT* won't propagate.

If you're using SSH, you can look into propagating it with [SendEnv](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5#SendEnv) or [SetEnv](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5#SetEnv) on the client side, and [AcceptEnv](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config.5#AcceptEnv) on the server side, but I wouldn't rely on it since it's not a typical default on most systems. You may also be able to set [PermitLocalCommand](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config.5#PermitLocalCommand) on the server and access your local environment with [~C](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh#_C) and `!echo $SCRIPT`, but again I wouldn't rely on it unless you control the server.